# Project: The Moving Ant

Tags: c#

I have a homework assignment and I really don't know where to start!
So I have summarized the assignment:

There's an ant moving through a 2D array. The ant can only go forward, backward, and sideways, but the direction should be randomized. The ant should move through the whole array and there should be a step-counter to see "how many steps" the ant has taken. Use struct in an advanced way

I'm not looking for the whole answer, I really want to try to solve it myself, but I'm really stuck on where I should begin. I don't want to sound stupid for not knowing but in new into the programming world and try to learn as much as I can!

I'm sorry if my English is bad, it's not my first language :D Thank you in advance!

Comment: This too broad for StackOverflow, but: take small steps! Do you know how to create a 2D array? Can you "move" through that array? Can you select a random direction to move into?  Can you prevent walking off the edge of the array? etc.

Comment: First create an 2D array and try to get values of that array forward, backward and sideways. Then you will find a way to get the step count.

Comment: Thank you guys for the tips, I will start with that!

Comment: Agreed. break the problem down into the smallest steps you can. Maybe write out your procedure on paper first (without any actual code) to see if you can figure out the logical steps. After that, it's easier to research and implement each individual step, as each one by itself is likely to be a smaller, and better-understood programming problem which you can find examples of

Comment: See Dijkstra Algorithm : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm